# Backbone - Issue when managing page transitions

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I'm trying to manage page transitions in backbone using the Derick Bailey's suggestion in this [article](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/), but the about route isn't rendering. It only renders the home route with app.BookListView, and when I click to access the about route, it stays the app.BookListView.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<section class="feed">
</section> 
<script id="bookTemplate" type="text/template">

        <div class="book">
        </div>

</script>

 <script id="aboutTemplate" type="text/template">

         <div class="about">
         Bla bla bla bla
         </div>

  </script>
```

The views

```
Backbone.View.prototype.close = function(){
   this.remove();
   this.unbind();
};

function AppView(){
    this.showView(view) {

        if (this.currentView){
        this.currentView.close();
        }

        this.currentView = view;
        this.currentView.render();
        $('.feed').html(this.currentView.el);
     }
 };

app.BookView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'book', 

template: _.template( $( '#bookTemplate' ).html()),

render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
)};

app.BookListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.feed',
    initialize: function ( initialBooks ) {
        this.collection = new app.BookList (initialBooks);
        this.render();
     },

    render: function() {
         this.collection.each(function( item ){
                this.renderBook( item );
         }, this);
     },

    renderBook: function ( item ) {
         var bookview = new app.BookView ({
              model: item
         })
         this.$el.append( bookview.render().el );
         } 
    });

 app.AboutView = Backbone.View.extend({
     tagName: 'div',
     className: 'about',

     template: _.template( $( '#aboutTemplate' ).html()),

     render: function () {
         this.$el.html(this.template());
         return this;
     }
 });
```

The router

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '' : 'home',
        'about' : 'about'
    },

    initialize: function(options){
        this.AppView = options.AppView;
    },

    home: function () {
         var homeView = new app.BookListView();
    this.AppView.showView(homeView);
    },

    about: function () {
          var aboutView = new app.AboutView();
          this.AppView.showView(aboutView);
    }
});

app.Router = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

And some data to test the BookView:

```
$(function(){
    var books = [
        {title:'Imperial Bedrooms'},
        {title:'Less than Zero'},
     ];
new app.BookListView (books);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swayziak/xdRRE/

The console throws this errors:

- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { , in "this.showView(view) {"
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'AppView' of undefined , in "this.AppView = options.AppView"

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried jslint?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't show any error that can be related with this problem

Answer (score 4):

You have syntax errors,....misplaced, or missing characters, undefined objects.

```
new app.BookListView (books);
```

<-- this should be:

```
var bookListView  =  new app.BookListView (books);
```

the following will not work :

```
  this.showView(view) {

    if (this.currentView){…
```

I assume you want this ?

```
this.showView = function(view){…}
```

The following line also throws an error:

```
app.BookView = Backbone.View.extend ({…)};
```

It should be:

```
app.BookView = Backbone.View.extend ({…});
```

For next line to work :

```
this.AppView.showView(homeView);
```

you have to pass `appview` here on initialization:

```
app.Router = new AppRouter(appView);
```

I'll try to clean up your fiddle, what kind of code editor are you using ? Because all the errors are syntax related.

**update**

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/jmR8e/)

The problem with your home route was on this line:

```
home: function () {
    if(!this.bookListView){
        this.bookListView = new app.BookListView();
    }
},
```

it should've been:

```
home: function () {
    if(!this.bookListView){
        this.bookListView = new app.BookListView(books);
    }else{
        this.bookListView.render();
    }
},
```

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 2. Thanks for your answer. I've made all that changes, but it still doesn't works.

Comment: The code in your jsFiddle, is that all code you have ?Can we see all  code, then i can look at it offline, jsFiddle is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: I have more a html sidebar with the about tag, the model, collection and a the Terms&View (which code is equal to the About view) in Javascript. I think the problem is related with the app.BookListView, because I already tried with another code in the router and the About and Privacy routes work properly, I have problems with the home route, here is the JSFiddle with the another router: http://jsfiddle.net/swayziak/Mm8Mt/. Maybe I can send you the code in an email or something. Thanks.

Comment: sure, e-mail is on my user page.

Comment: Thanks! but in your user page I only see your age and your location, but I don't see your e-mail

Comment: oops, sorry might've set it to private : rakhmetovruslan@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to sent you the email in the next 15min

Comment: sure, i'll look at it today(tonight)